# Setting shortcuts of Chrome on Mac

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I want to modify the shortcuts for opening a new tab. I did the following modifications:

[image: p1]

However, when I press `cmd+N`, chrome will still execute open a tab in a new window, but I want to open a new tab in this window.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also insert a 'garbage' command for New Window, otherwise it will 'win', as it will be first in the command list.

[image]

[image]

You also need to use the exact wording of any menu item you wish to change the command for. There is no such menu item as "Open a New Window".

Comment: It works, thanks!